# Can I call the loop methods from outside main function?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner; // needed for Scanner Class

public class MyClass
{
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   boolean running = true;
   
   GAME:
   {
       // Create a Scanner object for choice input.
       Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
       String gameName = "The Path";
       
       PATHCHOICES:
       while (running)
       {
           System.out.println("Enter your choice: Left, Right, or Run Away");
           String choice = console.nextLine();
           
           //make the do-while statement
           do
           {
               if (choice.equals("Left"))
               {
                   System.out.println("You choose to take the left fork in the road.");
                   break PATHCHOICES;
                   
               }
               else if (choice.equals("Right"))
               {
               System.out.println("You choose to take the right fork in the road.");
               break PATHCHOICES;
                   
               }
               else if (choice.equals("Run Away"))
               {
                   System.out.println("You choose to turn back and return the way you came.");
                   break PATHCHOICES;
                   
               }
               else
               {
                   System.out.println("please choose Left, Right, or Run Away");
                   choice = console.nextLine();
                   
               }
           } while (choice != "Left" && choice != "Right" && choice != "Run Away");
       }
       
       DOORCHOICES:
       while (running)
       {
           System.out.println("Enter your choice: Open The Door, Walk Away From The Door");
           String choice = console.nextLine();
           
          do
          {
              if (choice.equals("Open The Door"))
              {
                  System.out.println("You open the door and walk into the next room.");
                  break DOORCHOICES;
              }
              else if (choice.equals("Walk Away From The Door"))
              {
                  System.out.println("You walk away from the door and head back the way you came.");
                  break DOORCHOICES;
              }
              else
              {
                  System.out.println("Open the door or Walk Away From The Door");
                  choice = console.nextLine();
              }
          } while (choice != "Open The Door" && choice != "Walk Away From The Door");
       }
   }
   System.out.println("tacos");
   }
  }
```

Is it possible for me to call these loops methods into play without having to repeatedly type them out (copy paste)? I would like to be able to call the loops from outside the main GAME function if that’s possible. That way I don’t have to copy paste, copy paste, copy paste every time I want to use that same loop. I have both loops named PATHCHOICES AND DOORCHOICES, so if it is possible what syntax would I use?

Comment: You need to learn about [methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to create methods, in addition to many other improvements you could make. Here's a solution with methods and some improvements.

To start, here's a new method named "promptForDoor" which:

- Lines 2-3: define a few strings that you're going to re-use
- Line 5: start a loop here, simple "while", repeat forever
- Line 6: print the input options (using strings defined from 2-3); also, use "print()" instead of "println()"
- Line 9: check if their input matches with the string from Line 2, and use "equalsIgnoreCase()" since it doesn't matter what the user types in ("OPEN THE DOOR" or "open the door" should both work)
- Line 10-11: print something informative, then eject from the method altogether by returning "choice"; this also ends the loop
- Line 13-15: same logic as 9-11
- Line 17: if you make it here, it's because you didn't match on Lines 9 or 13, so just repeat the whole loop again (including the prompt to the user, and reading input)

```
1   private static String promptForDoor(Scanner scanner) {
2       String openTheDoor = "Open the door";
3       String walkAwayFromTheDoor = "walk away from the door";
4   
5       while (true) {
6           System.out.print(openTheDoor + ", or " + walkAwayFromTheDoor + "? ");
7           String choice = scanner.nextLine();
8   
9           if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase(openTheDoor)) {
10               System.out.println("You open the door and walk into the next room.");
11               return choice;
12   
13           } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase(walkAwayFromTheDoor)) {
14               System.out.println("You walk away from the door and head back the way you came.");
15               return choice;
16           }
17       }
18   }
```

Here's another method to prompt for path, it's the same structure as the other method.

```
1   private static String promptForPath(Scanner scanner) {
2       String left = "left";
3       String right = "right";
4       String runAway = "run away";
5   
6       while (true) {
7           System.out.print(left + ", " + right + ", or " + runAway + "? ");
8           String choice = scanner.nextLine();
9   
10           if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase(left)) {
11               System.out.println("You choose to take the left fork in the road.");
12               return choice;
13   
14           } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase(right)) {
15               System.out.println("You choose to take the right fork in the road.");
16               return choice;
17   
18           } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase(runAway)) {
19               System.out.println("You choose to turn back and return the way you came.");
20               return choice;
21           }
22       }
23   }
```

Here's an example to run it:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String path = promptForPath(scanner);
String door = promptForDoor(scanner);

System.out.println("path: " + path);
System.out.println("door: " + door);
```

Along with sample input+output – including an uppercase input ("LEFT") which works fine, and an unexpected input ("jjjjj") which resulted in re-prompting the user to enter something valid. Finally, it printed out each of the inputs captured from the user ("LEFT" and "walk away from the door").

```
left, right, or run away? LEFT
You choose to take the left fork in the road.
Open the door, or walk away from the door? jjjjj
Open the door, or walk away from the door? walk away from the door
You walk away from the door and head back the way you came.
path: LEFT
door: walk away from the door
```